# What do indices in brackets mean?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

Solving the Schrodinger equation for a free particle gives me this output:
[image: output image]
What does the $\psi^{(2,0)}$ mean here?

Comment: see [GeneratedParameters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeneratedParameters.html)

Comment: I can see that `K[1]` is a generated parameter here, but the formatting of $\psi$ doesn't seem to match?

Comment: $\psi^{(2,0)}$ is shorthand for the second derivative of $\psi$ in its first argument.

Comment: .. that is, `D[\[Psi][x, t], {x, 2}]`